Do conjugated cyclic matrices have the same cyclic vectors?
Let $F$ be a field and $A\in GL(n,F)$ a cyclic matrix, hence there exists a $v \in F^n =: V$ such that $v, Av, ..., A^{n-1}v$ span $V$. Now let $B \in GL(n,F)$ be a matrix which is similar to $A$, so there exists a $X \in GL(n,F)$ such that $XAX^{-1}  = B$.
An equivalent characterisation of cyclic matrices is that their characteristic and minimal polynomial are the same. It follows then that $B$ mus also be cyclic, since similar matrices share characteristic and minimal polynomials.
My question now is:
Given $A, B, v$ as above, is $v$ also a cyclic vector of $B$?
Thus far I have thought of the following:
$$\{v, Bv, ..., B^{n-1}v\} = \{XAX^{-1}, XAX^{-1}v,...,(XAX^{-1})^{n-1}v\} = \{XAX^{-1}, XAX^{-1}v,...,XA^{n-1}X^{-1}v\}$$
However it is not clear to me why (or why not) the above set should be linearly independent.
EDIT: Upon giving this more though it seems that the set should intuitively still span V, since conjugating matrices represents a change of basis, so all we do is apply the same transformation to v but with reference to another basis. Is that intuition correct and how would one go about proving this?

You need some proofreading/editing. What do you mean by saying $A\in V$? You repeat this with $B$. The obvious answer to your basic question is that you should take $Xv$ as the cyclic vector for $B$ (as that's the vector that corresponds to $v$ under the change of basis).

The vector $w = Xv$ will be a cyclic vector, since $\{w, Bw, \dots, B^{n-1}w\}$ will be equal to $\{Xv, XAv, XA^2v, \dots, XA^{n-1}v\}$, which is a basis multiplied by the invertible matrix $X$. However, $v$ itself might not be.
We can see this even in $\mathbb R^2$. Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and let $v = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$, so that $\{v, Av\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^2$. Let $B = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$: this is similar to $A$, with $X = X^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}.$ Then $Bv = v$, so $\{v, Bv\}$ is not a basis.

Thank you for the answer! Wouldn't ${v, XAX^{-1}v,...,XA^{n-1}v} also be a basis multiplied by two invertible matrices and hence also a basis? I am not sure I understand the why multiplication on the right would be a problem.

There's two problems. First of all, you can't multiply a column vector by a matrix on the right. Second, turning $XA^kv$ into $XA^kX^{-1}v$ isn't even multiplication on the right: you're inserting $X^{-1}$ into the middle.

I see, thank you!
